# How get count element in query select with Distinct?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
           t1.name as t1_name, 
           t1.unit as t1_unit, 
           t1.id_producer_goods AS hi_id_producer_goods, 
          t2.name as t2_name 
FROM Table1 t1 
    left join Table2 t2 on t1.id_web_site=t2.id_web_site 
WHERE t1.id='23'
```

How get count `t1.name` in it query?

I check code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
           t1.name as t1_name,
           count(t1.name) as count,           
           t1.unit as t1_unit, 
           t1.id_producer_goods AS hi_id_producer_goods, 
           t2.name as t2_name 
FROM Table1 t1 
    left join Table2 t2 on t1.id_web_site=t2.id_web_site 
WHERE t1.id='23'
```

But it code have error:

```
Column 'Table1.name' is invalid in the select list because
it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
```

I know that i write not aright in line `count(t1.name) as count,` but how get aright count `t1.name`?

P.S.: query get results with unique rows `t1.name, t1.unit, t1.id_producer_goods, t2.name`. Count `t1.name` should show all count each element `t1.name`.

Comment: For the count, you would want to use Group By rather than Distinct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to add

```
GROUP BY t1.name,t1.unit,hi.id_producer_goods,t2.name
```

Whenever you use an aggregate function along other columns, you have to add the group by clause for the remaining columns.

And for these you can remove the distinct. Group by will do it for you.

Comment: if i add `Group by`, should i use `Select Distinct...` or may be i should use only `select...`?
P.S.: becouse results already grouping...

Comment: No. You don't need to use distinct. When grouping you will only get distinct combinations and for each of them the respective count.

Comment: Big thanks +1, P.S.: i edit your answer becose i get some errors.